# Apply an animation dynamically to an HTML element

Tags: angular, angular-animations

My purpose is to apply a given animation to an html `div`, and the information about the name of this animation is based on the value contained in an Input variable in the angular component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css'],
  animations: [
    myFirstAnimation(),
    mySecondAnimation(),
    myThirdAnimation(),
  ]
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  /* 
   * The information about the name of the animation is containded in obj.animation
   * For example: obj.animation may contain '@myFirstAnimation',  '@mySecondAnimation' or '@myThirdAnimation'
   */
  @Input() obj: any;

  //...
}
```

How could I insert `obj.animation` as a `div` attribute in order to insert dynamically the animation into the `div`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve my problem from a different approach by using animation states.

In my HTML element, I always refer to the same animation:

```
<div [@myAnimation]="obj.animation">
```

where `obj.animation` may contain different states of the animation (for example: `state1`, `state2`,...).

The animation is defined for example as follows:

```
trigger('myAnimation', [
  transition('void => state1', [
      style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)', opacity: 0 }),
      animate(300, style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
    ]
  ),
  transition('void => state2', [
      style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)', opacity: 0 }),
      animate(300, style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', opacity: 1 }))
    ]
  ),
  //...
]);
```